# Tried to chroot user but broke SSH access

Tags: shell, ubuntu, ssh, console

I'd like to chroot user `a` to its homedir.

So I edited `sshd_config` and added these lines, right after `Subsystem sftp internal-sftp`:

```
Match Group agroup
    ChrootDirectory %h
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    AllowTcpForwarding no
```

Of course, `agroup` is a group that has only `a` as member. I saved the file, run `service ssh restart` and boom, I couldn't SSH anymore even with `root` (`PermitRootLogin` is on yes). Why? When I try to access I get "`No route to host`".
From the already open ssh connection I managed to edit `sshd_config` again and comment the new lines.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you reproduce this and get the `ssh -vvv` output from trying to connect? `No route to host` sounds like a networking (not ssh) issue to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your Match block is not at the end of your sshd_config, and that one of the lines appearing after your match block is necessary for your sshd to start properly.

from man sshd_config:

```
Match   Introduces a conditional block.  If all of the criteria on the Match line are
        satisfied, the keywords on the following lines override those set in the global
        section of the config file, until either another Match line or the end of the
        file.  If a keyword appears in multiple Match blocks that are satisified, only
        the first instance of the keyword is applied.
```

That is, anything after your Match block and before the end of file which is not another match block will be ignored.

I think if you move your Match block to the very end of sshd_config it should work for you.

Comment: Yep.. that's simple. :)